# Cant login to new CloudFoundry AWS deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud-foundry, paas

I just installed CloudFoundry on AWS using the docs [here](http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/deploying/ec2/bootstrap-aws-vpc.html).

However, now when i try to login to cloundfoundry i get the following:

```
root@cf-installer:~/releases# cf login -a api.mydomain.com -u admin -p the_admin_pw
API endpoint: api.mydomain.com
FAILED
Invalid SSL Cert for api.mydomain.com
TIP: Use 'cf api --skip-ssl-validation' to continue with an insecure API endpoint
```

So I did as the error msg told me to:

```
root@cf-installer:~/releases# cf api --skip-ssl-validation https://api.mydomain.com
Setting api endpoint to https://api.mydomain.com...
OK

API endpoint: https://api.mydomain.com (API version: 2.4.0)
Not logged in. Use 'cf login' to log in.
```

But even then I keep getting this:

```
root@cf-installer:~/releases# cf login -a api.mydomain.com -u admin -p the_admin_pw
API endpoint: api.mydomain.com
FAILED
Invalid SSL Cert for api.mydomain.com
TIP: Use 'cf api --skip-ssl-validation' to continue with an insecure API endpoint
```

What am i doing wrong?

**Update**

I tried Scott's method and got this:

```
root@cf-installer:~# cf login --skip-ssl-validation -a https://api.mydomain.com -u    admin -p the_admin_pw
API endpoint: https://api.mydomain.com
Authenticating...
Server error, status code: 500, error code: , message:

Password>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either do:

```
$ cf api --skip-ssl-validation https://api.mydomain.com
$ cf login -u admin -p the_admin_pw
```

or

```
$ cf login --skip-ssl-validation -a https://api.mydomain.com -u admin -p the_admin_pw
```

Comment: You are past your original problem and on to a completely separate issue now. You will have to dig into some logs to get more detail on what's happening. I would start with the Cloud Controller logs and then the UAA logs to see if you can get more detail.

Once you get this deep, I think you would have more luck posting your issue in the Cloud Foundry google group at https://groups.google.com/a/cloudfoundry.org/forum/#!forum/vcap-dev. You will get a lot more CF-knowledgeable eyes on the problem by posting to the group.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. This is a temporary work around that worked for me.

1. Downloaded the cert from https://uaa.mydomain.com. (you can do this from the browser).
2. scp the cert to all the Login Jobs (login_z1, login_z2 etc) instances using bosh scp.
3. ssh into the Login Jobs instances and added the cert as trusted to the java keystore using the java keytool. JDK will be present in /var/vcap/packages/xxxxxx/jdk
4. Restarted all login jobs using bosh restart.